# Determine the threshold value and number of regimes with delayed variable

Tags: r, time-series, time-varying-covariate

I am currently working on a threshold model for the exchange rate between UK and US. I have not got background knowledge on this model so I am really stuck on how to determine the Threshold value, number of regimes and delayed variables (d=?). I am currently using R.

From the book I read I noticed firstly I need to create a scatter plot of X(t) and X(t-k) , k=1,2... (lags) with an undersmoothed fitted curve. Then plot the residual against X(t-k) to determine the threshold value, number of regimes. Am I correct and how to plot these graphs in R?

Is there any package that I can use to deal with the threshold model in R?  Do I have to download S-Plus?

Comment: What book are you referring to? What is the threshold model you are referring to? Note that if you only want to know how to plot, & packages to use, etc in R, this question would be off-topic for CV, but questions about the model are on-topic here.

Comment: Hey Gung thank you for your quick reply, I just want to know the general procedure on how to deal with threshold model, how to determine the threshold value, delayed variables and number of regimes. It is better if I can have some idea on how to do it in the program eg:R, as this would save a lot of time on calculations. Thank you very much for your help! I am really new to this topic but I have some knowledge on time-series. If there is anything you want to know pleas let me know! :)

Comment: Yes, we would like to know what threshold model & what book you are referring to.

Comment: I think I will go for the Threshold autoregressive model with 2 regimes. And the book with title"Non-linear time series..Parametric and Non-parametric Methods_By Fan.J Yao.Q"

Comment: It is on page 140, I want to plot these graphs in order to determine the delayed parameter and threshold value.